# Mongodb Cloud Atlas ip whitelist

Tags: mongodb, meteor

A Meteor app uses Mongodb Cloud Atlas, in the whitelist for ip(s), there is the public ip address of the AWS EC2. But that EC2 also has a private IP. Which one should be allowed in the whitelist, the EC2 public or private? And why? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When first released, Atlas did not permit peering.

As of Nov 3, 2016 you may now peer your AWS VPC Client VPC to your MongoDB Atlas VPC.  This will permit you to bridge your private networks. You may then specify specific IP addresses from your private range of even security groups right into your Atlas whitelist.

This blog provides full details on the process to peer two VPCs.
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-vpc-peering-for-mongodb-atlas